# C# mvc controller to class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, razor

I wanna be clear that I'm super new to MVC, and have never done anything close to web development at all so keep that in mind.

My question is closely related to my title, but first here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a textarea, the user types some data, and clicks the action button. the text is then sent to my controller, where I want my controller to then pass that value to my class function. That function will do it's thing then return the value back to my controller which then updates the textarea again.

So far I only have the textarea which passes the value to my controller. What my question is, is how can I then have my controller talk to my class and then return the value to my textarea again...

```
public class TTHController : Controller
  {
    // GET: Text_To_Hex
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(string comment)
    {
        [Call calss here](comment)
        return "";
    }
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "TTH"))
{
  @Html.TextArea("comment")

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the "Model" element of your project.

Comment: `var obj = new myClass(); var retValue = obj.Method(comment);` this is what you need to wring in Post Action method of controller. Replace `MyClass` with your class name and `method` with a proper method name from your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should achieve what you need.

Create a model to hold the comments

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Comments {get;set;}
}

public class TTHController : Controller
  {
    // GET: Text_To_Hex
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
    {
        //Do class stuff
        //The comments will already be bound to the model in your post.
        //Just redirect passing in the same model.

        return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
    }
```

Use a TextAreaFor to bind to the comments model property

```
@model MyViewModel;

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "TTH"))
{
  @Html.TextAreaFor(x=> x.Comments);

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: It did thanks for the assist.